# How to update old Java Timer to new Java Timer with a TimerTask

Tags: java, timer, java-8

I have some older Java code that looks like this:

```
timer = new Timer( 1000, (ActionListener) this );
```

In the newest Java (I'm using Java 8 build 129 and JavaFX), Timer needs a TimerTask and I'm not sure how to attach that to my ActionListener...

Comment: can´t find this constructor at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html - what timer are you using?

Comment: That's the problem - I'm not sure what to use in this situation. I want to do:  Timer timer = new Timer();  timer.scheduleAtFixedRate( somehow integrate timertask with that ActionListener(this), 0, 1000);

Comment: The above code in the question is from an older version of Java - it's not current which is why I'm trying to change it. :)

Comment: can you check the imports? looks like some homonym wrapper class

Comment: @Leo There are two Timer classes in the jdk.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two Timer classes in the jdk: `java.util.Timer` and `javax.swing.Timer`. The one that takes an ActionListener is the latter. The one that works with TimerTasks is the former.

Note that the constructor's signature has not changed in [Java 8](http://download.java.net/jdk8/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html#Timer-int-java.awt.event.ActionListener-).

So you should probably check your imports.

NOTE: since you are upgrading to Java 8, you may as well take the opportunity to avoid obsolete classes (cf. javadocs) and use a `ScheduledExecutorService`.

Comment: ah - ok; java.util.Timer was pulled in automatically so I didn't think to check for other imports.  So yes, the original code still works.  I'll look into ScheduledExecutorService. Thanks!